# Was there a reason for network order to by big-endian?

Tags: networking, endianness

It seems like most modern(as in, past 20 years) processors have used little endian, or at least preferred it(if bi-endian). Was there a reason that they made big-endian the universal order for all network protocols? Is there any actual advantage to it, except for being easier to use for big-endian processors?

Comment: Your initial premise is incorrect - just because the x86 family is little endian it doesn't follow that "most modern processors" are little endian.

Comment: Does bi-endianness mean a preference for little-endian? Or does it mean preference for big endian with a compatibility mode to cope with the "all the world's a {VAX,i386}" syndrome?

Comment: The Intel chips were an abomination when they first came out - they still are but we're used to them now :-) There were much nicer architectures with more consistent addressing modes and the "correct" byte ordering, such as the 6800 lineage.

Comment: Read: [ON HOLY WARS AND A PLEA FOR PEACE](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt)

Comment: @lars well, for instance, referencing http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11535/how-to-choose-between-little-endian-or-big-endian-for-the-processor-settings the 6502 processor is faster in little endian. I'd wonder if other architectures aren't the same @pax well hell, the PDP-x architectures have nicer assembly code than the x86 :P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Big endian was probably chosen because the majority of computers of that era (what, the late 1960's?) used it.

How could they predict the popularity of the 80x86 family and its use of little endian so many years later?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#History):

> An often-cited argument in favor of
>   big-endian is that it is consistent
>   with the ordering commonly used in
>   natural languages.[9] Spoken languages
>   have a wide variety of organizations
>   of numbers: the decimal number 92
>   is/was spoken in English as
>   ninety-two, in German and Dutch as two
>   and ninety and in French as
>   four-twenty-twelve with a similar
>   system in Danish
>   (two-and-four-and-a-half-times-twenty).
>   However, numbers are written almost
>   universally in the Hindu-Arabic
>   numeral system, in which the most
>   significant digits are written first
>   in languages written left-to-right,
>   and last in languages written
>   right-to-left.